# Different CRC32 values from Linux and Windows with Python3

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, windows, crc32

I've been pulling my hair out with some mismatched CRC-32 values. Originally thought it was my own C# implementation at fault, but traced through common problems (binary vs text files, etc) and looking at the Python and zlib implementations.  Now I'm thinking it is something subtle in the hardware/file system. The following results are both with the following Python...

```
import binascii
buf = open("my_sample_file.zip","rb").read()
print(len(buf))
print( binascii.crc32(buf) & 0xffffffff )
```

First machine: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS. Intel 64 bit. Running Python 3.7.3, 64 bit (bit size confirmed with sys.maxsize).
This gives a length of 6239603497, and a CRC of 720283681.

Trying the same script on a Windows 10 PC 64 bit, Intel. Python 3.7.2 64 bit, I get a length of 6239603497 (good), and a CRC of 2907064737!

The zip file unzips fine, and the contents are good.

So why the difference?  As far as I can tell, both are using the same underlying zlib library. The only clue is that this is a very large file (around 6GB). Smaller hand-typed "hello world" tests give the same crc.

Currently thinking of dropping the CRC check and replacing with a simpler checksum or xor that I can code myself and has other advantages (eg. download chunks can by pre-calculated and combined at the end for speed).

Comment: The SHA1s are identical. Yes the Win10 version was downloaded through a 'file transfer program'. To do the sha1 I transferred it back to the ubuntu machine with a USB drive.  See above: the different CRC values are coming from an IDENTICAL Python program on two different machines/OSs, and almost identical versions of Python. binascii.crc32 is a part of the Python standard library.

Comment: Start small.  what does `binascii.crc32(b'1234')` return on both machines?  On my  PC it gives `2615402659`.

Comment: same here on both.

Comment: I'd guess this is a bug in one of your Pythons, with files greater than 4 GB...

Comment: That is the way I'm leaning. Or if not Python itself, then the underlying zlib. If so, surprised my searching on google, here, etc haven't found anything...   Just did a quick 32-bit wide xor checksum - my C# code (Windows) and Python (Ubuntu) matched. Python was slower than molasses but it should be easy to optimise.